# Django BooleanField as a dropdown

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to make a Django BooleanField a drop down in a form?

Right now it renders as a radio button. Is it possible to have a dropdown with options: 'Yes', 'No' ?

Currently my form definition for this field is:

```
attending = forms.BooleanField(required=True)
```

Comment: just change the widget

Comment: Maybe use a `Select` widget

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe a solution that can solve your problem is something along the lines of this:

```
TRUE_FALSE_CHOICES = (
    (True, 'Yes'),
    (False, 'No')
)

boolfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices = TRUE_FALSE_CHOICES, label="Some Label", 
                              initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

Might not be exact but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: worked great! Edits: Curly bracket for choices should be a parenthesis, missing an 'S' in TRUE_FALSE_CHOICE. I also used 1 and 0 for True and False, but I'm sure it works with the way you have it.

Comment: Using True, False is better because if you try to render an instance of the form, the appropriate value will be selected.

Comment: Can i use more than two choices in TRUE_FALSE_CHOICES ?

Comment: @Progam You should be able to yes.

Comment: But how can i do it ?

Comment: Did you try just adding more tuples to the choices and see if they show up in the field? That should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 22):

What you can do is add "choices" key word to your BooleanField in your models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))

    attending = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
```

Comment: I used this approach, but it seems it breaks ModelForm validation.
If neither Yes nor No is selected it crashes with an ValidationError when saving the model, no idea why it shows the form as valid if it's obviously not. (Django 1.11)

Comment: You should have passed the default parameter, either True or False at model level. This would have validated even if no data is passed.

Answer (score 5):

With a modelform

```
TRUE_FALSE_CHOICES = (
    (True, 'Yes'),
    (False, 'No')
)
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('attending',)
        widgets = {
            'attending': forms.Select(choices=TRUE_FALSE_CHOICES)
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that approach preselect "Yes"?