# How can I pass True into form if one field is selected and False if another

Tags: django, django-forms

I have select field in my html

```
<select class="form-select" name="is_recurrent" id="payment">
    <option value="False" class="option" selected>One-time fee</option>
    <option value="True" class="option">Subscription</option>
</select>
```

I have model Donate in models.py

```
class Donate(BaseModel):
    is_recurrent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

I have form in forms.py

```
class DonateForm(forms.Form):
    is_recurrent = fields.BooleanField(???)
    ...
```

How can I pass True into form if subscription is selected and false if one-time fee is selected

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Django-forms, it's really easy to do so, you don't even need to build the form! From your HTML code I can see you are trying to do so, creating an HTML form, I recommend you going through Django-forms information page [(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms) since you don't really need to create all of the input boxes, the Django Forms takes care of that for you, you just need to pass the variables you want to edit using the form.

Comment: but i need to use select there. If it's not difficult for you, can yot tell me how it should look like with the select?

Comment: I think you got the solution you need in this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398031/django-booleanfield-as-a-dropdown

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will try to do it

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your form in the view, you pass in the POST data:

```
form = DonateForm(data=request.POST)
```

That will auto-populate the form with the information that the user selected in the form prior to form submission.